# Flutter - http.get fails on macos build target: Connection failed

Tags: http, flutter, permissions, flutter-desktop

I started porting my Flutter app to **macos Desktop**. The UI started fine. However, as soon as the app makes a network call, it fails instantly with **Connection failed (OS Error: Operation not permitted)**.

Running a one-liner:

```
final response = await http.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1');
```

fails with:

```
Unhandled Exception: SocketException: Connection failed (OS Error: 
    Operation not permitted, errno = 1),
         address = jsonplaceholder.typicode.com, port = 443
#0      IOClient.send (package:http/src/io_client.dart:33:23)
```

The macos build target comes from Google's sample [here](https://github.com/google/flutter-desktop-embedding).

*Flutter (Channel master, v1.9.8-pre.108)*

Answer (score 65):

Per my comment on the other answer, you should **not** use the Xcode capabilities UI for this. It will not correctly handle the two separate entitlement files in a Flutter project.

You need to add:

```
<key>com.apple.security.network.client</key>
<true/>
```

to `macos/Runner/DebugProfile.entitlements` and `macos/Runner/Release.entitlements`.

This is documented [here](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/platform-integration/macos/building#setting-up-entitlements) and [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/entitlements/com_apple_security_network_client).

Comment: I can confirm that following the accepted solution did NOT add the entitlement to release, even though I had selected "All" in the capabilities.

I was skeptical but this should be the accepted answer IMO.

Comment: After editing these two files - do a full stop/start cycle in VSCode debugger for changes to take effect.

Comment: that's work for me in debug, have not test on release

Answer (score 33):

Your macOS XCode project **lacks Internet permission** called "Outgoing Connections (Client)".

Open your macos xcode project - [root]/macos/Runner.xcworkspace

Click "Runner" in Project navigator - general settings will show up. Select "Capabilities" from tabbar and tick option **"Outgoing Connections (Client)"**.

[image]

Rebuild your application inside XCode and launch the project.

Comment: You should *not* use the Capabilities UI for the macOS Flutter Runner. See https://github.com/google/flutter-desktop-embedding/blob/master/macOS-Security.md. It is very likely that you only enabled outgoing connections for either Debug+Profile or Release, but not both.

Comment: @smorgan Thanks for the clarification. I'm surprised the `<key>com.apple.security.network.client</key><true/>` was not enabled by default. However, the files in question are:  `/macos/Runner-DebugProfile.entitlements` and `/macos/Runner-Release.entitlements`.

Comment: Could you elaborate on why you expected it to be enabled by default? Internet access isn't enabled by default in Flutter for (release) Android either (https://flutter.dev/docs/deployment/android#reviewing-the-app-manifest), so this is consistent with how Flutter currently works (iOS doesn't have such a setting, so there's no way to compare there). Similarly, a default macOS project template in Xcode gives you a sandboxed application without internet access enabled. Is there a reason you expect Flutter for macOS to be less secure by default than Flutter for mobile or native macOS projects?

Comment: How to enable internet connection for flutter desktop app in IntelliJ?

Comment: @K.Os See the link in my first comment. I've also added it as a separate answer now.

Comment: @kosiara-BartoszKosarzycki Please consider removing or editing your answer; people who read your answer but not the comments on it are getting incorrect information on how they should add internet capabilities to a Flutter application.

Comment: Although I did everything completely, I cannot connect to the internet in the release version.

Comment: @kosiara-BartoszKosarzycki Thanks for the tip. Did work for me! Now I can fetch from localhost.

Answer (score 3):

If you are getting this error Only in Android release then `Internet` permission must be missing from `main` `manifest`. You just need to add `Internet` permission in `Manifest` file.

Just add this permission in manifest `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>`

There are three manifest file available in Android folder

```
app/src/debug
app/src/main
app/src/profile
```