# How to enable Flutter internet permission for macos desktop app?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-desktop, flutter-http

I am trying to develop Flutter app which will run also on destkop.
This app is using http package:

```
import 'package:http/http.dart'
```

When I am trying to perform http request I am getting this exception:

```
 SocketException: Connection failed (OS Error: Operation not permitted, errno = 1), address = firebasedynamiclinks.googleapis.com, port = 443
```

This app is working on Android and iOS, how to enable this permission for macos?

**I am using IntelliJ IDE, so this answer is not satisfying me [Flutter - http.get fails on macos build target: Connection failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57841871/flutter-http-get-fails-on-macos-build-target-connection-failed)**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Flutter - http.get fails on macos build target: Connection failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57841871/flutter-http-get-fails-on-macos-build-target-connection-failed)

Answer (score 141, accepted):

You need to add:

```
    <key>com.apple.security.network.client</key>
    <true/>
```

to `macos/Runner/DebugProfile.entitlements` and `macos/Runner/Release.entitlements`.

This is documented [here](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/data-and-backend/networking#macos).

Comment: Very important: do not add any whitespace to the <key> node, sth. your IDE might do on save when formatting this file. This will result in obscure code signing issues later on.

Comment: note: a Hot Reload doesn't apply these settings, you'll need to stop & restart the app to take effect

Comment: @TomTom101, Just to clarify your meaning for other readers, while you don't want whitespace between `<key>` and `</key>`, it is ok to add whitespace by indenting the `<true/>` value.

Answer (score 1):

you should give "Outgoing Connections (Client)" permission to your project through Xcode. for a complete explanation check [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57841872/9689717).

Comment: You should not do this with Xcode. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57841871/flutter-http-get-fails-on-macos-build-target-connection-failed/57841872#57841872 and my comment in the question you linked to.

Comment: Also is better to give the actual concrete absolute response here, with a side note to the link. Most likely that link will not exists when someone is reading the response.

Answer (score 0):

add:

```
<key>com.apple.security.network.client</key>
<true/>
```

to Locations in your project
`macos/Runner/DebugProfile.entitlements`
also to
`macos/Runner/Release.entitlements`.

**After adding this, do `flutter clean` your project. and rebuild it.**

Then,
You would likely not face below issue.

`"Outgoing Connections (Client)"` permission to project via Xcode.