# Dio Package doesnot work on Flutter Desktop App

Tags: flutter, http, desktop-application, dio

Dio is working perfectly well on both Android and iOS but when I try to run thesame code base on mac Desktop, the application launches but I  cant make any http call, I cant connect to any server. It just keeps timing out. I dont know maybe DIO is not compatuble with desktop yet.

This is the error I get

```
DioError [DioErrorType.other]: SocketException: Connection failed 
(OS Error: Operation not permitted, errno = 1), 
address = api.wykinkin.app, port = 443
```

Comment: can i see your dio setup code?

Answer (score 2):

I later discovered I needed to add:

```
<key>com.apple.security.network.client</key>
<true/>
```

to my macos/Runner/DebugProfile.entitlements and macos/Runner/Release.entitlements.
from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61201081/12096361)