# flutter: Could not start Dart VM service HTTP server:

Tags: flutter, dart, errno

```
Building macOS application...                                           
flutter: Could not start Dart VM service HTTP server:
SocketException: Failed to create server socket (OS Error: Operation not permitted, errno = 1),        address = 127.0.0.1, port = 0
#0      _NativeSocket.bind (dart:io-patch/socket_patch.dart:1032:7)
<asynchronous suspension>
#1      Server.startup.startServer (dart:vmservice_io/vmservice_server.dart:468:19)
<asynchronous suspension>
#2      Server.startup (dart:vmservice_io/vmservice_server.dart:487:11)
```

"I am learning Flutter, and I encountered an issue where the emulator couldn't connect to the internet when I started it. In order to resolve the problem, I tried various methods. Eventually, I managed to fix the issue of the emulator not connecting to the internet, but a new problem arose with the emulator. What's even more frustrating is that I'm not sure which step caused this outcome. I hope that someone can help me solve this problem. Thank you."

Comment: See [How to enable Flutter internet permission for macos desktop app?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61201081)